# Searching for JavaScript datepicker slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am searching for a datepicker that will give the user a date selecting slider 
(Something like [Moving Boxes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/MovingBoxes/#&slider1=3) )

Where I (the preload programmer) select a date, and the user can slide either way to change it by one day at a time.

I'm using `jquery`, but any other framework would work fine as well.

Comment: Great idea. Please make sure to let us know when you roll one!

Comment: It seems that I might have to create one...
I'll share when I Do. :)

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for the grammar edit (writing in a bit of a rush :) )
However I did mean that I, (the programmer) will select the initial date for the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you will find what you are looking for with [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Comment: The page has very limited space so it must be small and  a slider.
Thank you though...

Comment: I think you have to take it and adapt it or just create a new one :)

Comment: I understand you ... but what you're looking is very specific so specific development ...

Comment: Maybe it will be the next big thing :)

Comment: Do not forget to codeplex or googlecode it, I will follow you !

Comment: The correct answer is "Doesn't exist.." but I'll give you the credit for trying :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var baseDate = new Date(2011, 1-1, 1);
  $('#datepicker').datepicker(); // Initialise datepicker
  $('#slider').slider({ // Initialise slider
        slide: function(event, ui) { // As it slides
              var date = new Date(baseDate.getTime()); // Calculate the new date
              date.setDate(date.getDate() + ui.value);
              $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date); // And set into the datepicker
        }
  });
```

});